# Is using copper ferrule crimp on 240v range receptacle. acceptable?

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, range

I have a new 4 wire receptacle for a range connection, the wires are 6 guage stranded, which don't hold in the new receptacle. I used utilitech copper crimp ferrule's on the wire ends and tightened the receptacle screws down on them which did the real crimping - I don't have a true ferrule crimp tool.

Is this use copper ferrule on stranded copper for a 240V range receptacle acceptable by code and practice?

[image: copper ferrule crimp]

Comment: Is there a torque specified for tightening the connectors?

Answer (score 3):

### No, that's a terrible idea!

The set screws in the receptacle *are not designed to* compress a crimp ferrule.

All equipment in the North American market is supposed to be UL-listed (or other NRTL such as CSA or ETL... *note that CE is not one!*)  You must follow the installation instructions becuase those are the only conditions the equipment is tested or certified for.

Generally, we don't use ferrules in North American wiring.

**Since ALL #8 and #6 insulated wire is stranded**, the stranded wire is not the problem.

If your receptacle is not UL listed, that's the problem.

If it is UL listed, either the receptacle is unduly difficult to work with, or your splicing techniques aren't up to snuff.  Keep learning!

Comment: Stranded wire length of insert area minus about an 3/16th. The receptacle is a utilitech from Lowes. Maybe that's the issue, I will check the Depot for a better unit.

Answer (score 1):

**Likely not to code and possibly unsafe due to the unorthodox crimping method.**

*Disclaimer: I'm not familiar enough with US code. What follows is a bunch of guesses based on European regulations.*

No matter what the code says, it's safe to assume that where ferrules are approved,they have to be crimped as designed. Just screwing them down is unlikely to crimp them properly. It's fairly likely that doing so will just deform the ferrule so that it bulges outward on the sides, limiting the amount of compression applied to the wires inside. First thing you should do is grab each wire and pull hard. If it happens to even partially slide out,then give yourself three cheers, you've just averted a house fire.

When properly done (correct size, properly crimped) a ferrule mostly turns stranded wire into sort of solid core. The terminals need to be designed for that. Not sure how US code handles this, you might have to have the terminals approved specifically to accept a ferrule,or perhaps terminals for solid core are okay. Terminals designed for stranded wire won't work well with a ferrule on.

Comment: I pulled, which is why I put the crimp on ferrules. With the crimp on ferrules pulling doesn't pull the wires out. The range receptacle is what it is. 230V circuit wire 6-3 is stranded, that's normal for a range or dryer 8-3 in the US. The receptacle is a range receptacle for 4 wires. The receptacle has an issue with stranded because no matter how I put the wire in , it always came out. I put the crimp ons and cranked the screws down and the wires are tight and don't pull out. I never ran into this before so I am wondering.

Comment: Stranding is mandatory for #8 and larger insulated wires. As such, 50A sockets are only certified for stranded wire.  *A socket that doesn’t work with stranded wire will never be approved for a UL listing* because it would be useless in the US market... my concern is a faulty or fraudulent item from Amazon etc.

Comment: Keep in mind the goal is reliable **electrical** conductivity, not mechanical connection. Make sure you are using the socket as instructed and apply the torque specified if one is.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica   It's a utilitech from Lowes. Specifically labelled for range hook up. I have never had the issue before.

Comment: Are you putting the wire in the right place?  Turning the nut 100% counterclockwise (lefty-loosey) to the soft-stop before attempting to install the wire? Some of them sort-of encourage you to put the wire on the wrong side of the screw.   Utilitech is a pretty cheapo brand, but that's ridiculous.  Also, can you tell us the cable type?  Sockets are made for coarse-stranded wires such as NM or THWN, not fine-stranded wires such as anything starting with S.

Comment: The cable for our electric range has 4 coarse stranded aluminum conductors and has the original 50 A breaker still in place. The original built-in range was hard wired. Thirty years ago I replaced the range with a slide-in, put a box in the wall and connected the heavy stranded Al to a 4-slot receptacle rated for 50 A. As I tightened the contact screws they splayed out the stranded Al conductors. I really did not like the result. Could I test it with an IR thermometer?